# How to replace a specific character which occurs between 2 characters?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas series with the following values:

```
import pandas as pd
input_series = pd.Series(['9009.00', '909.99', '9999.00', '9000.00', '900900900.00', '9900.09'])
```

I want to generate a series which looks like this:

**EXPECTED SERIES**

```
9999.00
999.99
9999.00
9000.00
999999900.00
9999.99
```

The task is to replace all zeroes(0) that occur in between two nine's(9).
I have tried using `str.replace` util of pandas but had no success in doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom function with find first `9` by `find` and last `9` by `rfind` and replace only this subtrings:

```
input_series = pd.Series(['9009.00', '909.99', '9999.00', '9000.00',
                          '900900900.00', '9900.09'])

def rep(x):
    r = x[x.find('9'):x.rfind('9')+1]
    return x.replace(r, r.replace('0','9'))

input_series = input_series.apply(rep)
print (input_series)
0         9999.00
1          999.99
2         9999.00
3         9000.00
4    999999900.00
5         9999.99
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> input_series = pd.Series(['9009.00', '909.99', '9999.00', '9000.00', '900900900.00'])
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['input'] = input_series
>>> df['extract'] = df['input'].str.extract('(9[09]+9)').fillna('')
>>> df['out'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['input'].replace(x['extract'], x['extract'].replace('0', '9')), axis=1)
>>> df
          input  extract           out
0       9009.00     9009       9999.00
1        909.99      909        999.99
2       9999.00     9999       9999.00
3       9000.00                9000.00
4  900900900.00  9009009  999999900.00
```

**PS**

For the new case added, i.e. '9900.09' to '9999.99'

Update the regex to (9[09.]+9)